# How to insert HTML radio button value to SQL through ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Please, I'm stuck trying to send my radio button user choice to the aspx.cs file and sent it to SQL, so here's the code:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Status</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="row" id="row" runat="server">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" id="nsent" value="nsent" name="status" runat="server" checked="true">Not Sent
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" id="sent" value="sent" name="status" runat="server">Sent
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

So after I click Submit, there's a code to send it to SQL, but I don't have any idea how I would send the value selected in the HTML.
Selected Item or Selected Value won't work, even InnerText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for a radio button, and in WEBFORMS, you would look at both control's CHECK state

```
if (sent.Checked) == true {...}
if (nsent.Checked == true) {...}
```

Alternatively you could review the FORMS collection that was submitted with the Page.Request (if this is a POSTBACK).

```
if (page.request.forms["status"] == "sent") {
   ...
} elseif (page.request.forms["status"] =="nsent" {
   ...
}
```

A third option, which seems to be outside the scope of your question is to read the radio buttons on the client side, and submit the value to the server via some AJAX style submission.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<asp:Checkbox>` (ASP.NET WebForms) or `@Html.CheckBoxFor()` (ASP.NET MVC).